# Unable To Display Background Image

Tags: css, image, background

I am trying out responsive layout with 100% div wrapper and then placing a background image with text above and below it.

Unable to get it to display.

Looking to get the image to resize with browser window.

What am I doing wrong?

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

.image {
    background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Rivi%C3%A8re_Coulonge_Pont_Davidson_1024x768.JPG") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.text {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f5F6T/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to give height and width to your `.image` element. As well as a height to your wrapping div.

Answer (score 0):

You're .image is actually 0px heigh, that's why the image is not displayed.
Check out this :

just moved the .image code into the .text code :

```
.text {
    background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Rivi%C3%A8re_Coulonge_Pont_Davidson_1024x768.JPG") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f5F6T/1/

Edit :

```
.image {
    height: 30px;
    background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Rivi%C3%A8re_Coulonge_Pont_Davidson_1024x768.JPG") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f5F6T/3/

Comment: sorry to say bt u have set the background in **.text** and he also know how to set the background but he just want to know why the given code is not working so its better to tell the mistake or any other point..

Answer (score 0):

u need to set the content in middle div or give height. because initial div does nt have any height so how can u see the background??

check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5F6T/2/)-

--HTML--

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text">Give the height to below div!</div>    
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text">So, here u have ur photo</div>
</div>
```

--CSS--

```
.image {
   background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Rivi%C3%A8re_Coulonge_Pont_Davidson_1024x768.JPG") no-repeat center;
   background-size: cover;
   height:100px;
}
```

Comment: I set it to 600px and resized. At the start it changes both x & y direction but after certain point it only resizes x direction. Hope that make sense. I tried 100% height but that doesn't work. Is that limitation of css without using any script? Thoughts?

Comment: 100% height of what?? see until a container does not have content or a fixed height (200px, 500px etc) hoe can you see what u have in background?? its very logical point..